# Weird communication issues between 2 docker containers

Tags: php, docker, networking

I have two websites both in a docker container A and B running apache on the same docker network.
I have a simple php script `test_b.php` in container B

```
<?php
  print "test B";
```

In container A, I have a php script `test_comm.php` that calls `test_b.php` in container B using:

```
print file_get_contents(http://{name of container B}/test_b.php);
```

It works fine, I have "test" printed.

But now the weirdness, I have a script `test_a.php` with the following content:

```
<?php
      print "test A";
```

I modify `test_b.php` in container B to make a call to test_a.php:

```
<?php
print file_get_content("http://{container A name}/test_a.php");
```

Calling `test_comm.php` in container A,
I get a timeout; it seems http://{container A name} cannot be reached.

Any idea what is going on?

So, the issue seems that
`test_comm.php` on container A calls `test_b.php` on container B | Everything ok
In `test_b.php`, it calls `test_a.php` that is on container A | Container A does not seem to be reachable

If I call test_b.php directly on container B, it is able to call `test_a.php` that is on container A...

Edit:
docker-compose for container A:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    image: php:7.4-apache
    ports:
      - 8080:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
    networks:
      - mynetwork
networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: mynetwork
```

docker-compose for container B:

```
version: '3.1'

services:
  php:
    image: php:7.4-apache
    ports:
      - 8181:80
    volumes:
      - ./src:/var/www/html/
    networks:
      - mynetwork
networks:
  mynetwork:
    name: mynetwork
```

Comment: How are you launching the two containers; do you have the `docker-compose.yml` or a similar file?  Do you have the correct TCP port numbers on these cross-container calls?  Are both containers running HTTP services, or something else like PHP-FPM?

Comment: Are both containers able to see eachother? Connect to your container using bash and try to test their connection with `curl {container name}:{port}`.

You can also see if they are in the same network with the command `docker ps --format '{{ .ID }} {{ .Names }} {{ json .Networks }}'`

Comment: yes they can see each other.

it is when the calls are "nested", that it does not work.

Container A do a http request to http://containerB/test_b.php (works), inside test_b.php, there is a http request to http://containerA/test_a.php (does not work).

Comment: I added the docker-compose for both containers

Comment: Are you including ports in the url for the file_get_contents?